# What is a nullable operator in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am studying a code that uses guid data types using a ? , and sincerily I don't have idea about what means. ¿Can anybody helpme? 
Thanks in advance.

```
public Stream GetContent(Guid fileId, Guid? versionId = null)
{
     const string test = "Testing 1-2-3";

     // convert string to stream
     var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(test);
     var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
     return stream;
}
```

Comment: This means "Null" so the Field either would accept a value or a null . this is called nullable operator

Comment: Nullable types can represent all the values of an underlying type, and an additional null value. Nullable types are declared in one of two ways:
System.Nullable<T> variable
-or-
T? variable
T is the underlying type of the nullable type. T can be any value type including struct; it cannot be a reference type.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types

Answer (score -1):

This means `"Null"` so the Field either would accept a `value or a null` . this is called `nullable` operator

Comment: It doesn't mean "null", it means "nullable". It's also not called a nullable operator.